# How to align button toolbar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

No matter what I do I cant seem to get to align this button toolbar.This is how my html and css looks like. I've tried almost everything and toolbar is not centered on the page.

```
 <div class="row center">   
 <div class="btn-toolbar " style="justify-content: center; display: flex;"  role="toolbar"  aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
     <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label ="First group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" >Pretraži</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Poništi pretragu</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Snimi Excel</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Snimi PDF</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Novo  fizičko lice</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is css

```
  .btn {
    margin: 3rem; 
padding-left: 0px;
     background-color: blue;
        width: 160px;
        height: 50px; 
         display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
        align-content: center;
    }
    .btn-toolbar {
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: center;
        align-content: center;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row{
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.btn {
  padding-left: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
}

.btn-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-content: center;
}
```

```html
 <div class="row center">   
 <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar"  aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
     <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label ="First group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" >Pretraži</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Poništi pretragu</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Snimi Excel</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Snimi PDF</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Novo  fizičko lice</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like for buttons to be separated, but this code puts them on in one line

Comment: @Maida could you please share an image of expected behavior? I am a bit confused because with your code it is already aligned in the center but horizontally.